# How to change every even sequences in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change every even two elements in my array, for example:

```
arr = np.arange(0, 10)
arr
```

> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

```
mask = np.concatenate(np.split(np.arange(0, 10),5)[::2])   
arr[mask] += 100
arr
```

> array([100, 101,   2,   3, 104, 105,   6,   7, 108, 109])

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be with `modulus` -

```
arr[(np.arange(len(arr))//2)%2==0] += 100
```